# Echo and print language construct's out put

Tags: php, echo

Can any one explain in detail out put of the following statement

```
echo "1".print(2) + 3;
```

> Answer is = 511

Thanks.

Comment: what is the purpose of this code?

Comment: Glad this question was not in a past interview...

Comment: I got this from interview

Answer (score 4):

`print` is a language construct and doesn't require parentheses. You actually have these parts:

- string `"1"`
- `print`
- expression `(2) + 3`

which are executed in this order:

1. `(2) + 3` is evaluated, result `5`
2. `print` is executed with argument `5`, outputs `5`, returns `1` (because `print` always returns `1`)
3. expression `"1".1` is evaluated, result `"11"`
4. `"11"` is `echo`d

Answer (score 2):

```
`(2)+3 = 5` - and print it

concatenate the result of the print (true, because it succeeded, so `1`) with `1`, giving `11`.

echo that `11`
```

Comment: `print`: *"Returns 1, always."* - Not "true, because it succeeded".

Comment: yeah, true, but the principle still applies for getting 511 as the output.... answering old Zend certification questions is always points for old rope

Comment: I have just checked print documentation. It says 'Returns 1, always. '